# Run-Time Error '91' from otherwise working code

Tags: html, excel, vba

This code I have used in other places multiple times is unable to select this html element.

I've tried numerous variations of this code, getelementbyid, bytagname, by classname.

```vb
Dim DDList As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim DDOps As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim DDOp As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim DDOpID As Integer
Dim SM As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set HTMLDoc = ie.document

Set DDList = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName_
("reportViewer$ctl04$ctl15$ddValue")(0)
Set DDOps = DDList.getElementsByTagName("option")
DDOpID = 6
Set DDOp = DDOps(DDOpID)
DDOp.Click
```

Here is the HTML

```html
<SELECT id=reportViewer_ctl04_ctl15_ddValue class=aspNetDisabled 
style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; WIDTH: 127px" 
name=reportViewer$ctl04$ctl15$ddValue>  
<OPTION selected value=1>JANUARY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=2>FEBRUARY&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=3>MARCH&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=4>APRIL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=5>MAY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION>
<OPTION value=6>JUNE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=7>JULY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=8>AUGUST&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=9>SEPTEMBER&nbsp;</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=10>OCTOBER&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=11>NOVEMBER&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=12>DECEMBER&nbsp;&nbsp;</OPTION></SELECT>
```

I expect that this code will select the textbox on the webpage, instead it produces

> Run-time error '91': Object Variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: `reportViewer$ctl04$ctl15$ddValue` is a `name`, as opposed to an id or a class name. Use the id which is `reportViewer_ctl04_ctl15_ddValue`.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.